# Purpose of Adobe PDF Link Helper

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, adobe-reader, browser-plugin

I have an idea of what this browser add-on does.

*Adobe PDF Browser Control* (**AcroPDF.dll**)

Apparently, if I disable this one, PDFs embedded in a page with the embed or object tag fail to function properly. So, its pretty clear as to its function.

However, I can't find anywhere accurate documentation on what this add-on below does.

*Adobe PDF Link Helper* (**AcroIEHelperShim.dll**)

IE9 (with Reader X) seems to work flawlessly with it disabled.  PDF's still open *within* the browser.  Only if I uncheck **Display PDF in Browser** in Readers preferences does that cease.  I played around on an XP VM with IE7 and Reader X...  no isssues noticed when disabled.

Does anyone know the purpose of this add-on?  At one time I believed it was necissary for the 'within browser' functionality to work, though that was never verified.  Something change?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this link](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_Adobe_PDF_Link_Helper_This_is_an_add_on_and_i_am_trying_to_find_out_if_i_need_it_enabled_i_only_use_pdf_to_view_the_odd_user_giude_but_a_little_more_help_about_it_would_be_nice), it launches PDF files within the browser.

> With the Adobe PDF Link Helper (Reader Helper) - an Adobe Acrobat Reader browser add-on - you can view PDF files directly in Internet Explorer. When enabled, PDF files from websites launch automatically in your web browser. Enable/Disable the Adobe PDF Link Helper using the add-on management console in your browser: in Internet Explorer's Tools menu, choose Manage Add-ons/Toolbars and Extensions, then choose Adobe PDF Link Helper and click on the Enable or Disable button at the bottom right of the window.

Comment: It acually does that and therefore you can safely disable it. In fact you should disable it, because of more and more security holes in Adobe Reader product. If you disable this module, you don't have to face a situation where someone redirect you to malicious pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't "save" a document from a secured website tonight.  I enabled the Adobe .pdf link helper add-on and the document saved to my hard drive without the "access denied" error.  So, apparently this link helper is required, in certain situations.  -Allen in Chicago